# Distance Threshold using bluetooth

Tags: mobile, localization, bluetooth, nfc

I know many people have asked this about larger distances, but is there a way to determine using NFC/BLE/Bluetooth whether two phones are within a small distance of one another? (Say along the order of about 2-3 inches). Determination of precise location would be interesting to see, but not critical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a very low level, you can check the intensity of the signal.

I don't think you can code an apps who give you the precise distance, because it depends of the power of the emiter and the power of the receiver.ith less than 50 reputation.